# Logs in journald and syslog

Tags: systemd

I redirect the logs of journald to syslog with the option `ForwardToSyslog`. 
Although I would like keeping my logs in journald and having them in syslog.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

`ForwardToSyslog=` is documented in `man journald.conf`. It doesn't *redirect* logs to `syslog`, it *copies* the files there.

Do you have some indication that your logs send to syslog *aren't* in the `systemd` journal?

Comment: Since I put the ```ForwardToSyslog=``` my systemd journal doesn't have new logs. The logs are only in ```syslog```.

Comment: I found my mistake and it's nothing about ```systemd``` journal. It's only me who looked for the wrong element. Sorry about any inconveniences and thank you.